# Python YouTube downloader TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the following script to download a number of videos from youtube using `python youtube_dl`.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import pandas as pd

csv_file = 'movieClips_final.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

print(df.shape[0])
print(df.dtypes)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    file_name = ['/Users/yashar/Documents/GitHub/video_utils/download_video_youTube_python/' + str(row['movieId']) + '.mp4']
    print(file_name)
    ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': file_name}

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
         ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + row['youID']])
```

here is the error I recieve:

```
 (YT_download) d1:download_video_youTube_python yashar$ python   download_videos_YT.py
 6952
 movieId              int64
 title               object
 YTId                object
 Movie_clip_title    object
 youID               object
 dtype: object
         ['/Users/yashar/Documents/GitHub/video_utils/download_video_youTube_python/94.mp4']
 [youtube] 4K8M2EVnoKc: Downloading webpage
 [youtube] 4K8M2EVnoKc: Downloading video info webpage
 [youtube] 4K8M2EVnoKc: Extracting video information
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "download_videos_YT.py", line 17, in <module>
 ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + row['youID']])
 File "/Users/yashar/miniconda3/envs/YT_download/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2001, in download
url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))
 File "/Users/yashar/miniconda3/envs/YT_download/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 803, in extract_info
 return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
 File "/Users/yashar/miniconda3/envs/YT_download/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 857, in process_ie_result
return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
 File "/Users/yashar/miniconda3/envs/YT_download/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1635, in process_video_result
self.process_info(new_info)
File "/Users/yashar/miniconda3/envs/YT_download/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1713, in process_info
info_dict['_filename'] = filename = self.prepare_filename(info_dict)
File "/Users/yashar/miniconda3/envs/YT_download/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 665, in prepare_filename
mobj = re.search(FIELD_SIZE_COMPAT_RE, outtmpl)
File "/Users/yashar/miniconda3/envs/YT_download/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The column `movieId` has type `int`, that's why I use `str(row['movieId'])`. My downloader works if I use `ydl_opts={}` but I want to save the videos with specific name `movieIds` obtained from `movieClips_final.csv`.

Where do you think the problem is lying? Thanks for your feedbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outtmpl` expects a string, but you have:

```
file_name = ['/Users/yashar/Documents/GitHub/video_utils/download_video_youTube_python/' + str(row['movieId']) + '.mp4']
```

which creates a list with the filename as the first element.

So I think instead you want:

```
file_name = '/Users/yashar/Documents/GitHub/video_utils/download_video_youTube_python/' + str(row['movieId']) + '.mp4'
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem, I missed it!